# Telethon event.message doesn't handle captions but only returns images without the caption

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

In this example code, I am just forwarding messages from one channel to another

where watch_channels is a list of channels to observe for new messages, and output_channel is the channel to send those messages

When watch_channel has a image with caption, only the image gets sent to output_channel. The caption is left out.

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats = watch_channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):    
    me = await client.get_me()
    print(str(me))
    print(str(event.message.text))
    if me:
        await client.send_message(output_channel, event.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you just forward the message?

Comment: for some reason forwarding with the above method leaves out the caption